# How to change class of a div onclick in React

Tags: css, reactjs, event-handling, react-class-based-component

This is my code:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div  className='btndiv'>
        <button className='btn'>Hide</button>
      </div>
    );
}
```

When I click the button I want the class of the div to change from .btn.div to .btn divhidden, which basically dissapears it from screen.

```
.btndivhidden{
  display: none
}
```

I have watched multiple solutions but many of them are too complicated and put way too much code. How can I achieve this the most efficient and short way?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something relatively simple like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);

  const handleClick = () => setIsVisible(false);

  return (
    <div className={isVisible ? 'btndiv' : 'btndivhidden'}>
      <button className='btn' onClick={handleClick}>
        Hide
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to do this in react, but it gets it work done!! In the beginning I wasn't familiar with the react. So, I used to do these cheap ways to solve things. You can also try this if you feel like react is complicated, just to make yourself familiarize.

```
const hideClass = () => {
  const elem = document.querySelector(".btndiv");
  elem.classList.replace("btndiv", "btndivhidden");
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="btndiv">
        <button className="btn" onClick={() => hideClass()}>
          Hide
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isChange, setIsChange] = useState(true);

  const handleChange = () => setIsChange(!isChange);

  return (
    <div className={isChange ? "btndiv" : "btndivhidden"}>
      <button className="btn" onClick={handleChange}>
        Hide
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```